# Plotly: Remove extra blank space from hoverlabel

Tags: python, formatting, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y=['GOOG','AAPL'])
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified', yaxis_title=None, xaxis=dict(title=None,
                                                                      tickformat='%b\n%Y',
                                                                      hoverformat='%d %b %Y'),
                 hoverlabel=dict(namelength=0))
```

Using this code to plot gives me this hoverlabel on the graph-

[image]

As you can see, there's empty space between the two traces in the hoverlabel and not as much between the `date` and the first trace. How can I remove the empty space?

I want something more like this-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I figured this out. Have to pass the traces as if they are in the same legend group. The space probably exists because plotly calculates them to be in different groups. Adding `legendgroup = 'arbitrary_name'` to `fig.update_traces()` does the trick.

Here's the complete code to replicate -

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y=['GOOG','AAPL'])
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=None, legendgroup='a')
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified', yaxis_title=None, xaxis=dict(title=None,
                                                                      tickformat='%b\n%Y',
                                                                      hoverformat='%d %b %Y'),
                 hoverlabel=dict(namelength=0))
```

Note: This can also be exploited to add extra space in the hoverlabel by passing a trace (perhaps out of frame) with color matching that of bgcolor.